# Insert data from custom created PHP page into wp_postmeta table

Tags: posts, post-meta, wp-insert-post

I am working with a Wordpress site and have created a custom page in `/home/planmyme/public_html/php/` with the name `response.php`. On this page I am getting a value to insert in the `wp_postmeta` table (value examples: transaction ID, purchase ID, order ID, or item name), but I am not able to insert it.

I am using the code below as a test. I do not understand how to achieve this, or if there is any need of a database connection to run the query.

```
$metakey    = "_menu_item_type";
$metavalue  = "WordPress' database interface is like Sunday Morning: Easy.";

$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 
    "
        INSERT INTO $wpdb->wp_postmeta
        ( post_id, meta_key, meta_value )
        VALUES ( %d, %s, %s )
    ", 
    10, 
    $metakey, 
    $metavalue 
) );
```

Getting this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in
>   /home/planmyme/public_html/php/response.php on line 56

If anybody has an idea how to do this, please let me know.

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate. Try to search for `WP_USE_THEMES` on this site to find out how to include WordPress in an external script. But why don't you include your script directly into WordPress via plugin or a page template?

Comment: Have you defined "global $wpdb;" in your function ?

Answer (score 1):

The error message basically says that `$wpdb` is not an object so you can't call any methods on it. As we can't see where `$wpdb` is defined in the source you posted it's hard to tell any further details.

Are you even including wordpress in your external file? You need to require `wp-load.php` to use the wordpress functions and classes in an external application.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, your PHP file doesn't recognize $wpdb object.

To utilize WordPress functions within your PHP file, you should first add WordPress support by adding below to the top of your file:

```
<?php require('/the/path/to/your/wp-blog-header.php'); ?>
```

Then you can use $wpdb - after defining it:

```
<?php global $wpdb; ?>
```

Finally, you should use either the table prefix specifically or let $wpdb do it for you. Later is preferred so a change in table prefix won't affect your PHP file. Hence your SQL should be changed to:

```
INSERT INTO $wpdb->postmeta
```

..instead of `$wpdb->wp_postmeta`